# Valgrind support for TMS320DM365

Tags: linux, memory-leaks, arm

We have developed an application using ipnc_rdk version 5.0  for TMS320DM365 .
We have memory leak in the application.
We cross compiled valgrind for arm using arm- arago.
But when we run valgrind on the device, it shows illegal instruction error.

We saw couple of posts  telling that valgrind doesn't support armv5.
We got valgrind patches for armv5 at below link, but they fail to apply in the valgrind source.
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=248998
We tried applying patches for valgrind 3.9.0 3.8.1 & 3.2.1 versions

Is there a valgrind version for armv5 ?
If not how can we debug memory leak error in our application.

Also i ran top utility to check memory usage and there was increase in memory. Also kerenel calls oom killer. Please find the attached log which gives the top utility output and also the out of memory log

Top utility output just before oom killer was called:

```
shrd, 8K buff, 8352K cached  
CPU:  86% usr  13% sys   0% nic   0% idle   0% io   0% irq   0% sirq
Load average: 2.86 1.31 0.51 4/54 690
  PID  PPID USER     STAT   VSZ %MEM %CPU COMMAND
  663   655 root     R    59184 132%  97% /opt/ipnc/stillImage.out 
  668   655 root     R     3080   7%   3% top 
    1     0 root     S     1624   4%   0% init [5]   
  269     2 root     SW       0   0%   0% [kswapd0]
  627     1 root     S     6152  14%   0% ./boa -c /etc 
  655     1 root     S     3080   7%   0% -sh 
  529     1 root     S     2976   7%   0% /usr/sbin/inetd 
  651     1 root     S     2964   7%   0% /sbin/syslogd -n -C64 -m 20 
  653     1 root     S     2900   6%   0% /sbin/klogd -n 
  646     1 root     S     2900   6%   0% /usr/sbin/telnetd 
  634     1 root     S     2704   6%   0% avahi-daemon: running [10.local]      
  637     1 root     S     1940   4%   0% /usr/sbin/avahi-dnsconfd -D 
  630     1 root     S     1764   4%   0% avahi-autoipd: [eth0] bound 169.254.11
  631   630 root     S     1764   4%   0% avahi-autoipd: [eth0] callout dispatch
  622     2 root     SW       0   0%   0% [flush-1:0]
  620     2 root     SW       0   0%   0% [flush-ubifs_0_0]
    5     2 root     SW       0   0%   0% [kworker/u:0]
    4     2 root     SW       0   0%   0% [kworker/0:0]
    3     2 root     SW       0   0%   0% [ksoftirqd/0]
    2     0 root     SW       0   0%   0% [kthreadd]
stillImage.out invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x200da, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0
[   96.003955] Backtrace: 
[   96.006595] Function entered at [<c0030504>] from [<c03330c8>]
[   96.012605]  r7:00000042 r6:00000000 r5:000200da r4:c1f06000
[   96.018703] Function entered at [<c03330b0>] from [<c007cad0>]
[   96.024712] Function entered at [<c007ca58>] from [<c007cf50>]
[   96.030710] Function entered at [<c007cf00>] from [<c007d478>]
[   96.036727] Function entered at [<c007d1b4>] from [<c00809bc>]
[   96.042602] Function entered at [<c008056c>] from [<c007a5d0>]
[   96.048656] Function entered at [<c007a574>] from [<c0132024>]
[   96.054670] Function entered at [<c0131fb8>] from [<c00794bc>]
[   96.060669] Function entered at [<c00793cc>] from [<c007b6c8>]
[   96.066683] Function entered at [<c007b220>] from [<c007b78c>]
[   96.072694] Function entered at [<c007b718>] from [<c01317a8>]
[   96.078718] Function entered at [<c0131620>] from [<c00a2b34>]
[   96.084813] Function entered at [<c00a2a90>] from [<c00a35e8>]
[   96.090777]  r8:400b4000 r7:c1f07f70 r6:400b4000 r5:00001000 r4:c1d85680
[   96.098026] Function entered at [<c00a3534>] from [<c00a3738>]
[   96.103955]  r8:400b4000 r7:00001000 r6:c1d85680 r5:00000000 r4:0004e000
[   96.111222] Function entered at [<c00a36f4>] from [<c002d020>]
[   96.117225]  r8:c002d1a4 r7:00000004 r6:00351d08 r5:400b4000 r4:00001000
[   96.124460] Mem-info:
[   96.126777] DMA per-cpu:
[   96.129412] CPU    0: hi:    6, btch:   1 usd:   4
[   96.134472] active_anon:2952 inactive_anon:179 isolated_anon:0
[   96.134504]  active_file:95 inactive_file:192 isolated_file:0
[   96.134531]  unevictable:0 dirty:191 writeback:0 unstable:0
[   96.134557]  free:220 slab_reclaimable:86 slab_unreclaimable:437
[   96.134584]  mapped:154 shmem:1911 pagetables:71 bounce:0
[   96.163348] DMA free:880kB min:880kB low:1100kB high:1320kB active_anon:11808kBinactive_anon:716kB active_file:380kB inactive_file:768kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:48768kB mlocked:0kB dirty:764kB writeback:0kB mapped:616kB shmem:7644kB slab_reclaimable:344kB slab_unreclaimable:1748kB kernel_stack:432kB pagetables:284kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:1760 all_unreclaimable? yes
[   96.202321] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0
[   96.206059] DMA: 6*4kB 7*8kB 8*16kB 1*32kB 4*64kB 3*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 880kB
[   96.216739] 2198 total pagecache pages
[   96.224107] 12288 pages of RAM
[   96.227313] 317 free pages
[   96.230128] 1096 reserved pages
[   96.233410] 389 slab pages
[   96.236289] 187 pages shared
[   96.239319] 0 pages swap cached
[   96.242494] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss cpu oom_adj oom_score_adj name
[   96.250121] [  529]     0   529      744       20   0       0             0 inetd
[   96.257877] [  627]     0   627     1538       22   0       0             0 boa
[   96.265408] [  630]     0   630      441       20   0       0             0 avahi-autoipd
[   96.273789] [  631]     0   631      441       15   0       0             0 avahi-autoipd
[   96.282186] [  634]     0   634      676       54   0       0             0 avahi-daemon
[   96.290549] [  637]     0   637      485       22   0       0             0 avahi-dnsconfd
[   96.299030] [  646]     0   646      725       15   0       0             0 telnetd
[   96.306996] [  651]     0   651      741       34   0       0             0 syslogd
[   96.314876] [  653]     0   653      725       22   0       0             0 klogd
[   96.322563] [  655]     0   655      770       29   0       0             0 sh
[   96.330018] [  663]     0   663    14796     1080   0       0             0 stillImage.out
[   96.338552] [  668]     0   668      770       54   0       0             0 top
[   96.346062] Out of memory: Kill process 663 (stillImage.out) score 66 or sacrifice child
[   96.354411] Killed process 663 (stillImage.out) total-vm:59184kB, anon-rss:3824kB, file-rss:496kB
```

Thanks and Regards,

Arpitha

Comment: How did you identify that there is memory leak in your application. It would be nice if you can share bit about your application so that we can understand your problem.

Comment: I have interfaced TMS320DM365 with OV7955 image sensor.

I have  a function called createReference() which captures 15 continuous frames and generates a single reference image using these 15 frames.

I am mounting tmpfs on RAM and  these 15 frames are stored in tmpfs as initialImg1.YUV, initialImg2.YUV and so on. And right after generating the reference image,I am deleting these 15 frames and unmouting  tmpfs. The reference image will get stored in NAND.

When i call this createReference() in a loop, after few iterations, I encounter out of memory issue. So i thought there is some memory leak.

Comment: top shows that memory usage is 132% and last line of the log shows that kernel invoked the oom killer and killed stillimage.out, this concludes that stillimage.out is creating the memory leak.